# HTML button to run Python function

Tags: python, html, cgi

I have script, which is running under `CGIHTTPServer`.

Script contains:

```
$ cat cgi-bin/mysql.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "Content-Type: text/html"
print
print """
<html>
<body>
<h2>Test</h2>
<button type="button">Get version</button>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

And function (in other script or this):

```
def myver(host, user, pwd, cmd):
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host, user, pwd)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(cmd)
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    print "Database version : %s " % data
    db.close()

myver('localhost', 'username', 'megapass', 'SELECT VERSION()')
```

How can I get result of this function on to same web-page?

Links to **HowTo**'s will be perfect. Or some examples.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could do it better with jquery and Flask.

[Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is a Python microframework very easy to use and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is a javascript lib that makes Ajax a breeze.

Some code

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return """<html>
                   <head>
                      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
                      <script>
                           $(document).ready(function(){

                                $('#btnSend').click(function(){

                                    $.ajax({
                                      type: 'POST',
                                      url: '/process',
                                      success: function(data){
                                        alert(data);
                                      }
                                    });
                                });

                           });
                      </script>
                   </head>
                   <body>
                    <input type="button" id="btnSend" value="process">
                    </body>
                   </html>"""


@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def view_do_something():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        #your database process here
        return "OK"
    else:
        return "NO OK"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Try http:// localhost : 5000 in a browser.

Comment: Thanks, but this one is too complicated for me :-)

Comment: If you want to do anything more complex than the one-page app you posted in your question, Flask and jQuery will make your life a million times easier than trying to slog through the CGI way.

Comment: you're welcome, but listen to @robbrit advice. Jquery and Flask( or anyother Python web framework ) it's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by combining your two snippets:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


def myver(host, user, pwd, cmd):
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host, user, pwd)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(cmd)
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    print "Database version : %s " % data
    db.close()

print "Content-Type: text/html"
print
print """
<html>
<body>
<h2>Test</h2>
"""

myver('localhost', 'username', 'megapass', 'SELECT VERSION()')

print """
</body>
</html>
"""
```

If you would like to do this on the click of a button, you'll need to investigate AJAX and something a bit more flexible than CGI, such as [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Found next solution - using `GET`:

```
$ cat cgi-bin/mysql.py
#!/usr/bin/python

import cgi, MySQLdb

data = None
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

def myver(host, user, pwd, cmd):
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host, user, pwd)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(cmd)
    global data
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    db.close()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<title>Test to get MySQL version</title>"
print "<h2>MySQL version</h2>"
print '''Get version: <form action="/cgi-bin/mysql.py" method="get">
<input type="submit" name="getvers" value="Get version" />
<input type="submit" name="exit" value="Exit" />
</form>
'''

if "getvers" in form:
    myver('localhost', 'username', 'megapass', 'SELECT VERSION()')
    print 'Current MySQL version: ' + ''.join(data)
elif "exit" in form:
    print 'Exit'
```

Please, correct me if anything wrong... But - it works.

P.S. Can't run it with `POST` method :-(